# Troubleshooting 3:1 Audio Muxing with Relays. Crosstalk? How to test?

Tags: pcb, relay, multiplexer, layout, crosstalk

I am switching between 3 audio inputs out to 1 single output. Each input has 4 signals (left and right x positive and negative). I am using 4 DPDT relays (like 8 2:1 muxes).

Inputs 2 and 3 switch perfectly fine, however, any input on line 1 can be heard regardless of relay position. I was assuming crosstalk was the issue, however, I would expect that on line 2 and 3, not line 1 based on the image below, since they are much closer than line 1 to any other lines. There are at least 200 mils between any line 1 trace and any other trace. Line 2 and 3 signals do have some closer traces, however, this is for small lengths. Also the through-hole relays are at least 150mils apart. Based on Satur crosstalk calculator, this distances seem high enough, however, I think I am misunderstanding how this works.

These are Panansonic [TQ2-5V relays](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electric-works/TQ2-5V/251773). Note the inputs are already amplified coming into the board and are ~7.5 Vpp signals. The output is tied to 2 8-ohm speakers for left and right. Is this a crosstalk issue? Or perhaps are the relays inappropriately specced? Also, is there a simple way to test for crosstalk with just an oscilloscope?

EDIT: The issue was that Relay 4 would not switch. This is strange as it happened on 2 of 2 prototypes that were made. Simply replacing the relays on both fixed the issue. Trying to recreate the issue to see if I can "break" the relays again.

Comment: Can the signal from input 1 be heard at the same volume for all relay settings, or does it vary? Is the problem the same on both Left and Right?  I would use an ohmmeter to check all connections for all relay positions to see that the right connections are being made or broken.  If you are switching speaker-level signals I wouldn't expect crosstalk to be a problem.

Comment: @PeterBennett After checking back it seems that Relay 4 somehow became stuck and would not switch. I swapped it with a new one and now audio seems to be working, however, my 3rd audio source is currently broken and I am in the process of fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

If your crosstalk is inductive or capacitive, the amount of it will increase at high frequency. If it's something else, like a short, it usually won't. So you can simply test crosstalk at different frequencies to get an idea of what's happening.

That said, if the loads are 8 ohms speaker, it would be difficult for the tiny amount of capacitance or mutual inductance on your board to have an effect.

It's probably something dumber, like wrong relay pinout, short on internal layers, or one of the amps is bridged and there is a wrong ground connection somewhere.

Comment: I stated in the comment above, but you were correct that it wasn't crosstalk, one of the relays was stuck and would not switch even with 5V measured directly across the terminals and it was drawing more than the 30mA required.

Interestingly, the relay that I popped off that was stuck I then popped it in the same circuit on a breadboard and it worked fine. I also then tested a 2nd board and now that has the same problem with Relay 4 in the circuit being stuck. The first one is still functional but it now makes me wonder if somehow the TQ2-5V relays are not up to spec.

Comment: They are contact rated for 1 Amp. With 2 8ohm, 5W speakers. Not sure what the external amplifiers are rated, but measuring about 7.5Vpp signals.

Comment: That's pretty weird. Maybe contacts got welded by current or something?